# How to add the content in datagrid one after another

Tags: livecode

How I place the Search Result one after another in data grid. I am using the following code. it's works but it's only displays the the last line(Here f1 is main text field, f2 is searching filed. i am type a word in "f2" and if the word is present in f1 then that's line are place inside data grid one after another.)

```
on mouseUp
   if field "f2"  is not empty then   
   put field "f2" into gChar
   end if 


   local gname
   put empty into the field  "f2"  
   repeat for each line iText in field "f1" 
      if  iText contains gChar then
         put iText after gname
         set the dgText of group "data" to iText
  end if
  end repeat

   if gname not empty then

      put gname into the field "f2"
   end if

   if field "f2"  is empty then   
      put "" into field "f2"
   end if 

end mouseUp
```

Answer (score 1):

feel free to reference the datagrid API, but the basic command is

dispatch "AddData" to group "DataGrid" with theDataA, theLineNo

Here is a link to the datagrid documentation.

http://lessons.runrev.com/m/datagrid/l/7314-how-do-i-add-a-row-of-data-to-an-existing-data-grid